# Magento 2 How to extend Recently Viewed Products widget

Tags: widget, magento2.3.5, recently-viewed

I want to extend Recently Viewed Products widget so I can add review attribute.
After creating this file: `Vendor/MyModule/view/frontend/ui_component/widget_recently_viewed.xml`:

```xml
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="widget_columns">
        <column name="review" component="Vendor_MyModule/js/product/review" sortOrder="4" displayArea="details-area">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Review</label>
                <bodyTmpl>Vendor_MyModule/product/review</bodyTmpl>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

and clear cache, I got this error in browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return isMsrpApplicable($row()) }"
Message: isMsrpApplicable is not defined
```

How to properly extend this widget?

Answer (score 0):

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">widget_recently_viewed.recently_viewed_datasource</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <deps>
        <dep>widget_recently_viewed.recently_viewed_datasource</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
<dataSource name="recently_viewed_datasource" component="Magento_Catalog/js/product/provider">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="productStorageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">product_data_storage</item>
                    <item name="className" xsi:type="string">DataStorage</item>
                    <item name="updateRequestConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="serviceUrl" path="/products-render-info"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="identifiersConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">recently_viewed_product</item>
                </item>
                <item name="scopeConfig" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <dataProvider class="\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\DataProvider" name="recently_viewed_datasource">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName/>
            <primaryFieldName/>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
<columns name="widget_columns" component="Magepow_RecentlyViewed/js/product/list/listing" template="Magepow_RecentlyViewed/product/list/listing">
</columns>
```